# Search string in arraylist advanced (Java)

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have used the .equals method to search for a String in an ArrayList, but the user has to write the exact name of the String. Is there a way to show the String that matches the user input containing ?
If you for example search for 'Djang' and the String you are trying to find is 'Django'.

Comment: You could use a regular expression or something like `String#contains`

Comment: what do you mean by "name of the String"?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It measures how far away a string is from another string. There is even [a Java implementation in Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java).

Then, it's a matter of sorting and finding the minimum.

```
list.stream()
    .sort(Comparator.comparing(
            s -> LevenshteinDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(s, input))
    .findFirst();
```

From there, it's also possible to filter to add an upper bound on the acceptable distance to prevent all inputs from returning a result.

```
list.stream()
    .sort(Comparator.comparing(
            s -> LevenshteinDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(s, input))
    .filter(s -> LevenshteinDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(s, input) < limit)
    .findFirst();
```

Comment: The `LevenshteinDistance` is a good point. But I think the implements  is not that good. by using `LevenshteinDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance` directly in the `comparing`, this costly method would be called many more times. Maybe this can be done by `.filter` first, or use a map to store string and the metric.

Answer (score 0):

try the [String.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method

> public boolean contains(CharSequence s) Returns true if and only if
>   this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
>
> Parameters: 
>      s - the sequence to search for
>
> Returns: 
>     true if this string contains s, false otherwise
>
> Throws: 
>      NullPointerException - if s is null
>
> Since:
>   1.5

For example:

```
String myString = "Django"
public boolean stringCatcher(String userInput) {
    return myString.contains(userInput);
}
```

then passing `Djang` to `stringCatcher()` would result in a `true` value being returned.

Comment: That actually works pretty well. Guess it was kind of a noob question too, i feel like i should have known this or at least be able to search me to the answer:-). Thanks for the quick answer though!